# Tuleap and Mediawiki - Unable to create or edit pages

Tags: mediawiki, tuleap

I have enabled Mediawiki in a new project on Tuleap 8.3.99 on CentOS 6.6. However, neither the project members (including the project admin) nor the site admin can create or edit any page in the project.

The specific error shown is that Mediawiki is unable to perform the required operation due to a problem with the session and a suggestion to log out and log in again, which doesn't work either. I am using LDAP (AD actually) for authentication, and the rest of Tuleap works fine.

Any suggestions on how to get Mediawiki working correctly with Tuleap?

Added info: A check of the HTTP logs shows an error saying

> creation of a session file in `/var/tmp/tuleap_cache` has failed due to lack of permissions.

The directory itself is owned by codendiadm, which is the user under which httpd runs. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is not specific to Mediawiki; I was getting similar error messages on almost anything I did, including saving tracker report configurations. Incidentally, the tuleap_cache directory is owned by codendiadm and not root as incorrectly mentioned in the OP.

Solution: SELinux was in enforcing mode; changing it to permissive mode works.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permissions set (Administration link at MW service top) and ensure that the corresponding group (Project members in your case) as the write permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to mention that I did go to the "administration" link at the top of the MW service; it showed the mapping of groups between Tuleap and MW; I added the "project admins" group on the Tuleap side to "Admins" on the mediawiki side. By this, I assume that at least the project admin should have write permission; but this does not happen. I have also updated the post above with some more information.